# Cannot read property of '1' undefined error on change of form input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and trying to change the state of the values of a form when the user changes them. I have recreated the scenario [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/px2jyrxrx) I am getting a `Cannot read property '1' of undefined error` in the following line

```
      [this.get_schedule[key][field]]: value,
```

line of the `handleAmortScheduleChange` function. What is the reason for this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Which of the two key or field can have the value 1. Also lets print the value of this.get_schedule as it might be undefined. It can also be caused by this pointer if you are using it inside a function. In that case you need to use arrow function

Answer (score 0):

It's `this.state.get_schedule` instead of `this.get_schedule`...

And you could use arrow function to make the codes more clear: `handleAmortScheduleChange = (key, field) => (e) => {` and `onChange={this.handleAmortScheduleChange(key, "principal")}`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nn3mmvjkzp

Comment: I included your changes but I still am unable to change the input field values for principal and Interest .https://codesandbox.io/s/z29o2z1qv4

Comment: Yeah I have noticed that, but it's another topic...actually I'm not very sure what your application is trying to do. I guess some of the `value` should be replaced by something also inside `state`. If you put use input inside `state`, then you very likely want to put it back into some component.

Comment: My application gets the form values as an API response and stored in get_schedule. The user can change the values of principal and interest. The number of rows is dynamic depending on the API response and the sums of all Principals and Interests gets stored in a variable and displayed in Total Principal and Total interest fields. How do I make the input fields editable?

Comment: I think there are several js syntax misuses so `setState` is not working correctly, also the `<input>`s' values are not from `state` so your user input is not reflected on them. Check here for edited `handleAmortScheduleChange`, note the destructuring of `state` object, it's necessary to make it refreshed. Also check the `render` of `<input>`, all `values are corrected and is now from `state`.

Comment: I used your solution but I am getting Syntax Error : `Unexpected token error under the first = sign in the handleAmortScheduleChange = (field , key ,e ) => {` line.

Comment: I fixed my issue by installing transform class properties and then making suitable entries in babel.rc and the webpack config file. @Marson Mao your solution is working !

Comment: @AjaySingh Hey glad to hear that! I didn't think of the possibility of package problems...anyway it's good that you can make it work!

Comment: I just realised that the closing balance field isn't changing states as expected! https://codesandbox.io/s/w8x9j9o15